# How to set a ListObject equal to another ListObject?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set a ListObject to be an exact copy of another ListObject just like how you can set a range to be an exact copy of another range. Is this possible?

I've tried the following but it did not work:

```
Set destinationWorksheet.ListObjects("tblPriorTable") = sourceWorksheet.ListObjects("Table1")
```

It is important that the "tblPriorTable" ListObject not be deleted, because I have formulas in my workbook which reference that ListObject and those formulas break when the ListObject gets deleted. I just want to essentially overwrite the contents of "tblPriorTable" to be equal to another ListObject without ever deleting "tblPriorTable".

Comment: Maybe something like `destinationworksheet.ListObjects("tblPriorTable").value = sourceworksheet.ListObjects("Table1").value` might work?

Comment: @Mike No such luck. Value isn't a property of ListObjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a procedure like this:

```
Sub Copy_Contents(FromTable As ListObject, ToTable As ListObject)

    With ToTable
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        End If

        .Range(2, 1).Resize(FromTable.ListRows.Count, FromTable.ListColumns.Count).Value = FromTable.DataBodyRange.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that it assumes your two listobjects have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

The `ListObject` does not have a `.Copy` method, but a `Range` does:

```
Sub lksdhfs()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range
    r.Copy Range("g30")
End Sub
```

[image]

NOTE:

The copy produces another `ListObject`, not just a pile of cells.
Make sure the two tables do not overlap.

Comment: Ah, actually this doesn't work, because it deletes one of my ListObjects. I start with two ListObjects called "Table1" and "tblPriorTable". I need "tblPriorTable" to become the same as "Table1". With your answer, I end up with "tblPriorTable" deleted and a completely new (third) table. This causes my other formulas in the workbook to break since tblPriorTable no longer exists.

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero  The only time I have seen the copy fail, is if I try to put the copied table in the same set of rows as the original.